# Extract individual coefficients from plm model (R)

Tags: r, panel-data, plm

I would like to ask if it is possible to extract coefficients for individual observations for a given variable in panel data using `plm` in R, for instance using the example data:

```
wi <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
```

In other words, in this example a coefficient for each of the firms in the sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the function `fixef` in the plm package, which extracts the "fixed effects" (firm coefficients in this case). In your example:

```
library(plm)
data("Grunfeld")
wi <- plm(inv ~ value + capital, data = Grunfeld, model = "within", effect = "twoways")
```

and then run:

```
> fixef(wi)
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9 
-134.227709   72.826531 -269.458508  -38.873866 -139.666304  -31.339066  -82.761099  -66.737194 -104.010153 
         10 
  -7.390586
```

Comment: Not really. What I am interested in is calculating an elasticity for one observation, let's say for capital.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you are looking for:

> 1) "coefficients for individual observations"

vs.

> 2) "a coefficient for each of the firms"
>   .

These are two different things and I believe you cannot have neither.

1) Asking for more than one coefficient for one observation does not work.

2) Asking for one coefficient per firm but trying to estimate two (`value` and `capital`) does not seem plausible.

Maybe this answer gives what you are looking for:
[Extract all individual slope coefficient from pooled OLS estimation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232076/extract-all-individual-slope-coefficient-from-pooled-ols-estimation-in-r/46237581#46237581)